# Finding array elements when the sum of sub-arrays are given

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

> An array of N elements is given indexed from 1 to N. All elements are unknown and integers. Given some queries in the form of A, B, C where A is the starting index, B is the ending index and C is the sum of all elements between A and B inclusive. Find out all the elements of array. Example:
>
> ```
> N=4
> 1, 3, 0
> 2, 4, 4
> ```
>
> One valid solution to this is:
>
> ```
> 2, -3, 1, 6
> ```
>
> Constraints:
>
> ```
> 1<=A<=B<=N, 2<=N<=65000, C<=1000000000
> ```
>
> Any solution fulfilling the given criteria is accepted and assume enough queries are given to find out all the elements.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not homework. I want to apply cramer's rule after modeling these as linear equations but N is too high to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is by treating the problem as a series of simultaneous equations.  Each summation gives you a linear equation in up to n variables, so if you can find a solution to that equation that has integer values you should be all set.

Using Gaussian Elimination on a series of n variables with k different constraints takes (assuming that n = O(k)) O(k<sup>3</sup>) time on expectation (assuming the system is well-conditioned).  From there, finding integer solutions should be easy; just find the common denominator of any one solution vector and multiply through by it.

Hope this helps!